# Completeness detection analysis Plot of magnitudes of galaxies

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, galaxy, astropy

I have a magnitude data from the observation. I would like to find the detection completeness of the magnitude. I want to plot the figure like this in python
[image]

How to plot the Detection completeness and magnitude of my [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XxQmSyTSGNsq4X8M2FFzw3VlrJlBwnE0/view?usp=sharing)

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.table import Table

data = Table.read('magnitude_data.fits')
plt.hist(data['NB921'], bins=30)
```

Please let me know how to plot like this.

Comment: There's an [arXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.02650) (see Figure 4) that creates a similar plot. They don't use astropy, but they do have a [python library](https://github.com/inonchiu/ComEst) that derives the completeness estimates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is, but try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   
Data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Other_Data = [9.8,12,8,7.2,6.9,7,6.5,6.2,5.5,6.3]
  
plt.plot(Data, Other_Data, color='red', marker='o')
plt.title('Data Vs Other_Data', fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel('Data', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Other_Data', fontsize=14)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

The code creates a line graph and plots the data in **data** and **other_data**.

Also, try extracting your data out of that file and putting it in those strings.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: I made it a little better. Thanks :)

Comment: That;s much better actually, thanks. You can still improve it by explaining what it is the code does and why you think it will help solve the OP's problem.